# How to get all dashboard with “/rest/api/3/dashboard” api?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api, jira-agile

I am new to Jira and I want to get all the dashboards of a user.

So I go through the [link](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-dashboard-get) and got that by this **/rest/api/3/dashboard** URL I can find all the dashboards and also got one more point that **Apps cannot access this REST resource**.

Right now I have created Jira platform REST API APP and using its client_id and getting access_token by Auth 2.0 (3LO) but by this authentication process, I am not getting the all dashboard.

Is there any other authentication process I have to follow to get all dashboard as it is mentioned Apps cannot access this REST resource? please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried basic auth? You need to supply your email paired with your API token as password. Do note that your API token can be generated by following [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html)

Comment: I have to authenticate a user with rest but in this case, how can I generate this token with REST means here user is creating his own token from his account

Answer (score 0):

in my case，rest/api/3 not work, I use rest/api/2 instead.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

def auth(name, password):
    return HTTPBasicAuth(name, password)

def get_dashboard(auth, id):

    url = f"https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/dashboard/{id}"
    headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json"
    }
    response = requests.request(
        "GET",
        url,
        headers=headers,
        auth=auth
    )

    print(response.json())
```

then call this fuction:

```
auth = auth("username", "password")
get_all_dashboard(auth, 20)
```

it returns 20 dashboard now.

```
{
'startAt': 0,
'maxResults': 20,
'total': 811,
'next': 'https://jira.xxxxx.com/rest/api/2/dashboard?maxResults=2&startAt=2',
'dashboards': [{
    'id': '10943',
    'name': 'qqqqq',
    'self': 'https://jira.xxxxx.com/rest/api/2/dashboard/10943',
    'view': 'https://jira.xxxxx.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=10943'
}, {
    'id': '10953',
    'name': 'wwwww',
    'self': 'https://jira.xxxxx.com/rest/api/2/dashboard/10953',
    'view': 'https://jira.xxxxx.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa?selectPageId=10953'
}]
}
```